Facing issue while setup Expensify App on local npm i giving error "npm ERR! Unable to resolve reference $expo"
Getting error while install npm in package dependency expo
npm ERR! Unable to resolve reference $expo
(https://i.sstatic.net/mkshmgDs.png)
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\mayan\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2024-05-13T11_02_58_788Z-debug-0.log
Package.json is showing dependency as:
dependency: (https://i.sstatic.net/k416gRb8.png)
overrides: (https://i.sstatic.net/J4foMH2C.png)
(https://i.sstatic.net/8Mso1YwT.png)
I am trying to setup Expensify App code on local.

installed NVM and node
getting error in npm i

When i tried with 2 command npm install --legacy-peer-deps
getting this error (https://i.sstatic.net/vT5HjgKo.png)
sometimes show enable to remove dir error too.
Not able to install package dependencies due to this error.
